# Sort random values from a normal distribution based on knowing the distribution parameters

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, sorting

I aim to sort random values from a normal distribution, but solely based on knowing the distribution parameters (mean and standard deviation) without resorting to traditional sorting algorithms.

Since there is an analytical solution to a normal distribution, knowing its mean and standard deviation, **I am interested in mathematical relationships to transform these distribution parameters into positions in a sorted array.**

**Example:**

```
import scipy.stats as stats

normal_random_numbers = stats.norm.rvs(loc=0, scale=1, size = 10)
print(normal_random_numbers)
```

**normal_random_numbers:**

[ 0.410343    0.4965627  -1.68420462  0.40416681  0.69845175  0.25564581
-0.17941806  2.40900137 -0.46117301 -0.24580336]

```
#mathematical relationship to transform 
#these distribution parameters loc=0, scale=1 into 
#positions in a sorted array
```

**positions_in_sorted_array:**

[6 7 0 5 8 4 3 9 1 2]

What is the mathematical relationship to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "estimate the position of those values in a sorted array, purely based on that normal distribution mean and standard deviation"? Can you provide an example input and the desired output?

Comment: A normal distribution is supported on the whole real number line.  Have your values from $0$ to $1$ been relocated and rescaled so the minimum is $0$ and maximum $1$ or has something else happened?

Comment: I have now edited my answer to remove the additional confusion introduced by minimal and maximal values. It is not necessary to consider min and max anymore.

Comment: Without knowing the motivation, it's hard to give an answer. You essentially shuffle a list using a sample from a normal distribution. Are you interested in knowing the distribution of permutations generated this way? It might be a good idea to check the order statistics of a random sample from a normal distribution.

Comment: Depending on your sorting algorithm, knowledge of the parameters can help improve your initial guesses of where to place the values; but (a) it will not improve the asymptotic performance and (b) the amount of improvement depends on details of the algorithm.  As an example, you could use this knowledge to (potentially) improve the speed of a Quicksort by choosing the splitting values appropriately.

Comment: The suggestion for improving Quicksort is nice. Honestly, I was aiming to hit that O(log n) execution time mentioned on the wiki page from Order statistics, while the sorting algorithm has O(n log n) execution time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic